# How to selfhost .net core 3.1 web api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Can any one suggest with example how to selfhost core web API without IIS. I have hosted in the IIS but i want to perfome self hosting and also i want to enable HTTPS for the selfhost web API

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web API project you create using VS (VS code or command) is self hosted. The code can run both on IIS and outside of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

1. To Self host web api you should refer to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api)
2. To enable https

On an elevated console (“Run as administrator”), execute
`netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:4443/ user=<your user name>`
to allow the running user to listen on port 4443 using HTTPS (note the use of `https` instead of `http` in the above command).

Also on an elevated console, register the server certificate by running

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:port certhash=thumbprint appid={
    app-guid
}
```

where,
port is the listening port (e.g. 4443); the special IP address 0.0.0.0 matches any IP address for the local machine;
thumbprint is the certificate’s SHA-1 hash, represented in hexadecimal;
app-guid is any GUID (e.g. {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}) , used to identity the owning application.
Write self host configuration like

```
class MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration : HttpSelfHostConfiguration
{
    public MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration(string baseAddress): base(baseAddress){}
    public MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration(Uri baseAddress) : base(baseAddress){}
    protected override BindingParameterCollection OnConfigureBinding(HttpBinding httpBinding)
    {
        httpBinding.Security.Mode = HttpBindingSecurityMode.Transport;
        return base.OnConfigureBinding(httpBinding);
    }
}
```

then Change the base address passed to the MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration constructor: var config = new MyHttpsSelfHostConfiguration(“https://localhost:4443”);

Comment: I think this is for .net frame work , can i use the same for .net core web APi also ?